# How do I integrate with AMD format with brunch.js

Tags: javascript, amd, brunch

According to brunch docs AMD format can be configured so that modules are wrapped in AMD:

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#modules

Here is my brunch config:

```
exports.config = {
    paths: {
        watched: [
            'src/styles/',
            'src/scripts/'
        ],
        public: 'public'
    },
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: {
                'scripts/vendor.js': /^src\/vendor/,
                'scripts/head.js': /^src\/scripts\/head/,
                'scripts/foot.js': /^src\/scripts\/foot/
            }
        }
    },
    modules: {
        definition: 'amd',
        wrapper: 'amd'
    }
};
```

what I'm expecting is to see any files under src/scripts wrapped with a define wrapper:

```
define(['mymodule'] , function ($) {
    return function () {};
});
```

Am I missing some part of the configuration?